# How exactly are array pointers created if no brackets are used with a specified size in C?

Tags: c, pointers

I am pretty confused with pointers in C. I am finding it hard to wrap my mind around creating them and passing stuff around? I have a "Segmentation Fault: 11" error after I added code, in which previously it worked. Needed to add something. This is part of the code:

```
char *token2;
char *line2;
char comma_loc = 0;
int num_of_commas = 0;
char *line2[1];

while(token != NULL) { //lets make sure token has a string token
        //printf("Wats in token: %s\n", token);
        if(key==true) {
            //printf("This should be an identifier: %s\n", token);

            if(comma != true) { //added if statement, just take away if it fails, the first case is the original
            int len = strlen(token);
            iden_holder[iden_holder_count] = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * (len +1));
            memcpy(iden_holder[iden_holder_count], token, len +1);
            iden_holder_count++;
            key = false;
            } else {

                int len2 = strlen(token);
                line2[0] = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * (len2 + 1));
                memcpy(line2[0], token, len2 + 1);
                token2 = strtok(line2[0],",");
                    while(token2 != NULL) {
                            int len = strlen(token2);
                            iden_holder[iden_holder_count] = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * (len +1));
                            memcpy(iden_holder[iden_holder_count], token, len +1);
                            iden_holder_count++;
                            token2 = strtok(line2[0],",");
                        }
                key = false;

            }
```

Point of this code is to take the string within token and copy it into another token, in my case token2. I decided to use memcpy, but I am confused how to use it due to the pointers confusion. I should also note that I used strtok before this, and the code here is within in. Could it be that if I use it again that it will override the other one?

Comment: Read [6. Arrays and Pointers](http://c-faq.com/~scs/cgi-bin/faqcat.cgi?sec=aryptr) of the c.lang.faq very carefully, especially Questions 6.2 and 6.3.

Comment: Thank a lot @Jesse ! That explanation page on pointers is the best I have seen. And it makes it make sense. I really appreciate it.

Comment: No problem, if you have time, read the entire thing from front to back :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read [this](http://cslibrary.stanford.edu/102/) completely. It will help you with your basics. It did to me. :)

Comment: Also learn to use a debugger so you can figure out what line of code your segmentation fault is happening on and see the values of all your variables when it happens.

Comment: Thanks for the link, and I will definitely look into it @DavidGrayson thank you

Answer (score 1):

Pointers are exactly that: pointers. They're meant to point to something. The vast majority of problems people have with pointers is that they're not pointing anywhere intelligent :-)

Consider the following code:

```
char xyzzy[] = "hello";
char *pch;
```

In a stack-based C implementation, this will probably give you a stack containing the string and a pointer set to an arbitrary value.

The pointer *exists* on the stack like any other variable but it could point to anywhere.

If you then execute:

```
pch = xyzzy;
```

it's set to point to the first character of `xyzzy` (the `h`).

Arrays and pointers are *very* different beasts. For example, you cannot increment `xyzzy` to point to the second character of that string but you can increment `pch`.

The confusion arises because, in quite a *lot* of circumstances, arrays will decay to a pointer to the first element of that array.

*That's* basically the reason why you don't need `[]` for pointers, because they're not arrays. They do not know, and do not care, about how many things may exist at the memory they point at, their only concern is the *one* thing they currently point to.

Moving the pointer throughout the array, and ensuring you don't go off the ends, is extra management that you have to do as a programmer.

Comment: What do you mean by `you cannot increment xyzzy to point to the second character of that string`. Doing `*(xyzzy + 1)` is fine.

Comment: @Jesse, that's not _incrementing_ `xyzzy`, it's an expression calculating `xyzzy + 1`, leaving `xyzzy` untouched. I mean you cannot do something like `xyzzy++`.

Comment: I see, I misinterpreted incrementing as meaning just "adding". Thanks.

Comment: So just to understand what you mean, somewhere in memory is the character array "hello". So what does xyzzy hold? I was under the assumption that it would point to the first character of that array. So doesn't it hold an address just like pch would when making it equal to xyzzy, meaning xyzzy++ would be valid wouldn't it? It would just point to the second character?